# ¿cómo se puede asignar dos 'arrays' (arreglos) para que una función devuelva a dos variables de 'array' que tienen el sigilo de 'array' (@)?

Tags: raku

Tengo una función que devuelve dos 'array', pero tenía la dificultad en asignar estos resultados a dos variables de 'array'.

```
my (@A, @N) = volver_dos_arrays;

dd @A;  # muestra lo que está dentro de @A (dd = "data dumper")
dd @N;  

sub volver_dos_arrays
{
    my @alfa = <A B C>;
    my @num  = 1, 2, 3;
    return @alfa, @num;
}
```

Resulta en lo siguiente: en que podemos ver que el primer 'array' guardó los dos 'array' que devolvió la función:

```
Array @A = [["A", "B", "C"], [1, 2, 3]]
Array @N = []
```

Pero, yo quería que fuera así:

```
Array @A = ["A", "B", "C"]
Array @N = [1, 2, 3]
```

Sé que lo siguiente funciona, pero no me gusta guardar un 'array' en un 'scalar'. No quiero cambiar el sigilo de la `@A` ni de la `@N`.

```
my ($A, $N) = volver_dos_arrays;

dd $A;
dd $N;

sub volver_dos_arrays
{
    my @alpha = <A B C>;
    my @num   = 1, 2, 3;
    return @alpha, @num;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto sin cambiar los sigilos?

---

<sub>Aprendí cómo hacerlo, pero todavía hago la pregunta porque me dejó perplejo por un par de horas. Hago una respuesta si nadie da una respuesta similar a lo que averigüé.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente como ha dicho la otra respuesta, con arreglos, hay que usar una asignación de enlace:

```
my (@A, @N) := volver_dos_arrays();
```

Podemos ver el por qué usando otros valores:

```
sub volver-valores { 1,2,3,4 }
my ($a,$b) = volver-valores();
say $a; # 1
say $b; # 2
```

Cuando usamos una asignación en lista (con `my ( … )`), cada variable consume valores de acuerdo con su sigilo, y se descartan los valores no necesitados.  Así, `$a`, siendo scalar, consume un valor (`1`), y `$b` también consume otro.  Los demás (`3`, `4`) se descartan.

Si tenemos un arreglo con su sigilo correspondiente, los últimos valores no se descartan, sino que el arreglo los consume como elementos:

```
sub volver-valores { 1,2,3,4 }
my ($a,@b) = volver-valores();
say $a; # 1
say @b; # 2 3 4
```

Ahora, imagino, se puede ver el problema.  Si el primer elemento de la asignación es arreglo, consumirá ya todos los valores, dejando que el segundo tenga el valor por omisión (vacío, en el caso de arreglos):

```
sub volver-valores { 1,2,3,4 }
my (@a,@b) = volver-valores();
say @a; # 1 2 3 4
say @b; # [vacío]
```

Cuando usamos la asignación de enlace, los arreglos no consumen elementos para formar el arreglo.  Ya no podemos usar el sub anterior, porque si lo usamos:

```
sub volver-valores { 1,2,3,4 }
my (@a,@b) := volver-valores();
# Type check failed in binding to parameter '@a'; expected Positional but got Int (1)
```

Vemos que está intentando hacer que el arreglo sea `1`.  Pero un arreglo no puede ser un entero (aunque puede *contener* enteros), por eso falla.  Ahora cambiamos de sub:

```
sub volver-valores { (1,2,3),<a b c> }
my (@a,@b) := volver-valores();
say @a; # 1 2 3
say @b; # a b c
```

Pero ¡ojo! el tipo de `@a` y `@b` no es Array, sino List.  Esto es porque en la asignación de enlace en lista, decimos «que @a sea el primer valor» (y no «que `@a` se haga a base del primer valor).  Si usásemos una asignación normal, ya la diferencia está clara:

```
sub volver-valores { (1,2,3),<a b c> }
my (@a,@b) = volver-valores();
say @a; # [1 2 3  a b c] (un arreglo de dos elementos de tipo List)
say @b; # [vacío]
```

Ahora, hemos dicho «que `@a` se componga de los siguientes valores», y estos dos valores son una lista `1,2,3` y otra lista `a,b,c`.

Answer (score 2):

Solo he encontrado la solución del "binding":

```perl
my (@A, @N) := volver_dos_arrays();
```